# get local Storage items in a $listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have some issues with the HTML5 "localStorage".
I can save my values thats not the problem. (window.localStorage.setItem(key,value) but now I want to put this values into a list ($listview from jquery.mobile)
so this would looks like a contact list. For example, I store some names and in the next step this stored names should be inside a list (like the android contact list).
 I have no clue how to make this work.

```
var content = {
    children: [ 
        {type:'$listview',autodividers:true, filter:true, filterplaceholder:'contact Person'
            children: [
                {type:'$listviewitem',label:'localStorage.getItem(key), clickable:true, key:'o'}
            ]},         ^single Items aren't the problem
```

I iterated over my values but it dont work.

I need help with this.

Comment: Is stored as string in one localStorage space, there are different localstorage for each value. Elaborate the question

Answer (score 0):

To set local storage value for example

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla');
```

To retrieve the value

```
var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
// -> "vanilla"
```

To remove item form local storage

```
localStorage.removeItem('favoriteflavor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS

```
function processForm(){
  var telephone = document.myform.telephone.value;
  var maile = document.myform.maile.value;

  localStorage.setItem("telephone", telephone);
  localStorage.setItem("maile", maile);

  alert("Saved: " + localStorage.getItem("telephone") + ", " + localStorage.getItem("maile"));
}

function clearForm(){
  $('#myform').get(0).reset();
}

function retrieveFormInfo(){
  var telephone = localStorage.getItem("telephone");
  $("#telephone2").html("Phone: " + telephone);

  var maile = localStorage.getItem("maile");
  $("#maile").html("Mail: " + maile);
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="mensajes">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>mensajes</h1>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p><a href="#form" data-role="button" id="garform" onClick="clearForm();" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Enter Notes</a></p>
    <p><a href="#register" data-role="button" id="garSaved" onClick="retrieveFormInfo();" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Display</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="form">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Enter INFO</h1>
    <a href="#mensajes" id="save-activity-button" onClick="processForm();" data-icon="check" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Save</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="get">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="name">Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="theTelephone" value=""  />
        <label for="name">Mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="maile" id="theMail" value=""  />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ------------------REGISTER ------------ -->

<div data-role="page" id="register">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Register </h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content"> 
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li id="telephone2" ></li>
      <li id="maile"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured out what is going wrong. I used the Framework Zen Mojo, so I didn´t test your solution. My problem was, that I don´t add the list to my data property. So my layout obj. didn´t get my storage values. 

Best regards,
Blank